# Value to update attribute of primefaces command button

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a query here regarding the value given to the update attribute of the primefaces command button.

Here is a simple code. I have a simple xhtml page

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="main">
    <p:growl id="maingrowl" showDetail="true"></p:growl>
    <p:panelGrid id="mainpanel" columns="2">

            <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" update="test" id="ajax"
                actionListener="#{mytestBean.display}" />


    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:panelGrid id="test" rendered="#{mytestBean.show}" columns="1">
        <h:inputText value="#{mytestBean.val1}" />
        <h:inputText value="#{mytestBean.val2}" />
        <p:commandButton value="value in" id="aj" update="test"
            actionListener="#{mytestBean.displaysec}">
            </p:commandButton>
    </p:panelGrid>

</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Now, If I have to update the panelgrid "test" then in the first command button I have to provide the id "test" prefixed with ":main:" in the update attribute of the command button since that is the exact id in the HTML DOM as I find it in the *view source* in the browser. But, I was able to update even by given just "test" in the update attribute.
So my question here is when should I use the ":" in the id or is it mandatory or is there any pre defined rule to give the id's in the attribute?

Also, I am aware of the fact that the id given in the update attribute is through the UINamingContainer in which it is placed. Please pardon me if its trivial, I am really confused here.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both components (the one to update and the one that triggers the update) are inside the same NamingContainer, the relative client id withoud the `:` is sufficient.

NamingContainers in jsf are all those components that prepend their own id to the client id of all child components, e.g. `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>` (or to be more precise: all components that implement the [`javax.faces.component.NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) interface).

If both components are *not*  inside the same NamingContainer, you have to use the absolute id beginning with a `:` from the view root.

If you are interested in more detailed information I recommend reading the javadoc of the [UIComponent#findComponent()](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) method where the search algorithm is described.

Note that the `:` is the default character to separate segments of a clientId. You can change it with a context parameter in your `web.xml`.

Comment: If I give view source, the id of the component which has to be rendered will have the id prefixed by ":". So you mean it does not matter whether it has that id , I can still refer it by just the ID to render the component is it? I hope you got my point.

Comment: If they are inside the same container (and this is the case in your example) the simple client id of the component is just fine.

Comment: ok.. That clears all (Hopefully :)) . I will test in few other cases. Thanks for the clarifications.